# Traffic Shaping Dlink Router

Tags: windows-7, router, traffic-shaping

I have dlink router DIR-524. I want to set traffic shaping and QOS on my wifi router but these options are not available on the firmware that is installed on the router. I want to upgrade this firmware but no update is available on DLink website. Where can I get the firmware which has these options and incase something wrong happens after installing the new firmware, is there a way to go back to the default/original firmware?

I am on Windows 7

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would suggest using Tomato or DD-WRT, but the [dd wiki indicates the 524 is not suitable](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Known_incompatible_devices).

So in this case I'd suggest spending approximately £20 and buying a new router with QoS built in.

Comment: +1 must agree.  With the exceptionally low prices of home routers, and the large number of DD-WRT routers out there (along with the extensive support on the site for installing the firmware) you are far better off looking for a replacement router that either has the features you want, or a router you can install DD-WRT on.